# How to vectorize comparison of subsequent rows

Tags: r, compare, data.table, rows, vectorization

I am trying to speed up my current implementation for the following problem:

The arrival of an article `articleID` ordered in a `period` is determined through its `leadtime`, which varies from period to period. I would like to determine the number of times, an article has been `overtaken`, i.e. an article ordered in a later period arrived earlier than an article ordered earlier.

My current implementation (yes, two ugly for-loops):

```
library(data.table)
lt <- CJ(articleID=c("A", "B", "C"), period=1:100)
lt$leadtime <- round(runif(length(lt$period))*100,0)
lt[, arrival:=period+leadtime]
setkey(lt,articleID,period)

overtakenSum <- 0

for (art in unique(lt$articleID)) {
    for (p in sort(unique(lt[art,period]))) {

        # find subsequent period of item where arrival is before arrival period of article in current period
        overtakenSum <- overtakenSum + 
                           sum(lt[art==articleID & period>p,arrival] < 
                               lt[.(art,p),arrival])
     }
print(overtakenSum)
}
```

The implementation is too slow for the number of articles and periods I need to consider.

Is there a way to

- vectorize these operations (like with some advanced use of *diff*) or
- take advantage of special functions in data.table?

Comment: There is `shift` in `data.table`  with options `type="lag"` or `lead`

Comment: I'm seeing 0 0 0 from that loop. Is that right? Seems like a non-representative example if that's the desired result for it.

Comment: sorry, there was a mistake in the data generation for this SO example. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you can avoid the basically by-row part of your problem, since the various sums for each row don't appear to have a relationship with each other. However, with a simple rewriting of your solution I see a speedup of about 3x:

```
lt[, {perArt = .SD; # renaming, to be able to run the next line correctly
      perArt[, sum(perArt[period > p, arrival] < arrival), by = .(p = period)][, sum(V1)]}
   , by = articleID][, cumsum(V1)]
#[1] 1450 2599 3760
```